# Solrnet - How to initialize instance with basic authentication

Tags: c#, .net, basic-authentication, solrnet

It is possible to connect solr instance with basic authentication ?

I have tried with :

```
Startup.Init<Page>("http://user:mdp@localhost:8080/solr");
```

But it doesn't work.

have you got a solution ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a `IHttpWebRequestFactory` that returns an authenticated web request. See http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=66

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string solrUser = "user"; // replace with your credentials
string solrPwd = "mdp"; // replace with your credentials

var connection = new SolrConnection("http://localhost:8080/solr")
            {
                HttpWebRequestFactory = new HttpWebAdapters.BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory(solrUser, solrPwd)
            };

Startup.Init<Page>(connection);
```